# How to copy std::map value into non-container array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map that is populated with an id, and an array of floats. I'd like to copy the floats (pair.second) into *temp_arr.

```
// Temp object
struct Temp
{
    float t1, t2, t3; 
    float n1, n2, n3;
};

// A map that is populated.
std::map<int, Temp> temps;

// temps gets populated ...

int i = 0;
Temps *temp_arr = new Temp[9];

// currently, I do something like ...
for (auto& tmp : temps)
    temp_arr[i++] = tmp.second;

// here's what I tried ...
std::for_each(temps.begin(), temps.end(), [&](std::pair<int, Temp> &tmp) {
        temp_arr[i++] = tmp.second;
});
```

I was trying to do this using std::copy and I think a lambda would be needed to get a map of tmp.seconds into the temp_arr, but so far, not yet.

Comment: Show us the attempt that failed and explain what went wrong with it. And why are you trying to replace perfectly reasonable and working code? What's the benefit in that?

Comment: I keep reading how much better std::copy is than mempy which I've replaced w/ the for loop and since I'm not sure I've got that correct (because my renderings aren't working as expected), I thought I'd leave more of it up to the std::copy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the codes runs fine in my laptop, maybe is a problem with the microchip

Comment: @DamianLattenero Must be! 

Comment: Still can't see your `std::copy` attempt. It was probably very close.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my attempt was the for_each that I added, I was unable to do it with copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::copy` isn't appropriate here.  Instead, you can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::transform(temps.begin(), temps.end(), temp_arr,
               [](const std::pair<const int, Temp>& entry) {
                   return entry.second;
               });
```